# Why I can't display two windows with QtCreator eventhough they have the same code?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I tried to display two windows by copying the basic window's code. I just created a new Qt Designer Form (a Widget to be specific) called window which created a window.ui file, and I created a window.h and window.cpp where I put the same code we find in the widget files.

My main.cpp file :

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "window.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    Window p;
    p.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I find no problem with the .pro file :

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    widget.cpp \
    window.cpp

HEADERS += \
    widget.h \
    window.h

FORMS += \
    widget.ui \
    window.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

And for the .cpp and .h files for the window and widget classes, they're exactly the same. Well I just changed Widget by Window for the constructors...

When I run the program, It just displays the main window (from the Widget class) twice. I don't understand why the second ui isn't the window from Window class.

I hope you can help me understand what the problem is. I think It's because I didn't link the Window.ui file with the Window.cpp and Window.h but isn't it the role of the .pro file ?

I think it's better if I attach the window source code because there is no problem with the widget one (since it's automatically generated by QtCreator).
So here is window.cpp :

```
#include "window.h"
#include "ui_window.h"

Window::Window(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Window::~Window()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And here is the window.h :

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Window();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

And finally the window.ui :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Window</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Window">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>618</width>
    <height>439</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>110</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>311</width>
     <height>101</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>BROOOGH</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I get some errors : " allocation of incomplete type 'Ui::Widget' " in the sixth line of the window.cpp, and " member access to incomplete type 'Ui:Widget' " in the eighth line, and " deleting pointer to incomplete type 'Ui::Widget' may cause indefined behavior " in the thirteenth line.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: The MOC uses the .ui files to create header files that contain all the code that builds the window/widget/whatever. In your window.cpp file, there should be an include at the top for `ui_window.h`. Make sure this included header is a different file from the one in your widget.cpp file. If they are the same, then that's why the two windows look the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I included the #include "ui_window.h" in the window.cpp file I had the problem allocation of incomplete type 'Ui::Widget' with my constructor (it's code is simply the same as the one in the widget.cpp I have the namespace Ui  {class Widget; } in the window.h). What disturbs me is that in the window.ui file, the xml codes displays <class>Form</class> and not <class>Window</class>. I don't know if it's related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please attach at least one of widget/window source codes.
I guess you don't update member variable in class to point to classes generated from form files (something like: "Ui::Widget *ui;" -> "Ui::Window *ui;" and allocation should be changed as well in relevant ctor.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I've attached the window.cpp and window.h files.

Comment: Did you try proposed change?
Look like - as mentioned; you have included '#include "ui_window.h"' but you are trying to instantiate Widget class. You have to update your window.h with forward declaration for Window and the same in window.cpp - the allocation is not for Ui::Widget but for Ui::Window (? I guess, I don't know your form file) class comming from ui_window.h

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a Widget class :/ I added the ui_window.ui so you have the details.

Comment: @Daviiid please add minimum example, not only a part.